# Show data related to same id in one row php laravel

Tags: php, mysql, laravel

I want to show all the four types of divisions (marriage, birth/death, acting marriage, acting birth/death) related to same person in one row.
Following is my database table structure

registrar table-

```
 registrar id | name
 1            | reg1
```

registrar_has_division table-

```
id | registrar id | division id | is_acting
1  | 1            | 10          |0
2  | 1            | 11          |0
3  | 1            | 12          |1
4  | 1            | 13          |1
```

division Table-

```
division id | division name | division type
10          | Hulftsdrop    | 1
11          | Modara        | 2
12          | Slave Island  | 1
13          | Fort          | 2
```

here division type 1 is for marriage division and 2 is for birth/death division

Following is the query I wrote-

```
SELECT
    r.id AS rid,
    r.name,
    IF(
        divi.div_type = 1 && rd.is_acting = 0,
        divi.name_english,
        NULL
    ) AS marriage_div,
    IF(
        divi.div_type = 2 && rd.is_acting = 0,
        divi.name_english,
        NULL
    ) AS bd_div,
    IF(
        divi.div_type = 1 && rd.is_acting = 1,
        divi.name_english,
        NULL
    ) AS acting_marriage_div,
    IF(
        divi.div_type = 2 && rd.is_acting = 1,
        divi.name_english,
        NULL
    ) AS acting_bd_div
FROM
    `registrar` AS `r`
INNER JOIN `registrar_has_division` AS `rd`
ON
    `rd`.`registrar_id` = `r`.`id`
INNER JOIN `registrar_division` AS `divi`
ON
    `rd`.`division_id` = `divi`.`id`
```

result-

```
rid | name | marriage_div | b/d_div | acting_marriage_div | acting_bd_div
1   | reg1 | NULL         | Modara  | NULL                | NULL
1   | reg1 | Hulftsdrop   | NULL    | NULL                | NULL
1   | reg1 | NULL         | NULL    | Slave Island        | NULL
1   | reg1 | NULL         | NULL    | NULL                | Fort
```

I want the result as follows

```
 rid | name | marriage_div | b/d_div | acting_marriage_div | acting_bd_div
   1 | reg1 | Hulftsdrop   | Modara  | Slave Island        | Fort
```

I think that problem is in my if else statements in the query. I tried a lot, but I failed.
Any help would be grateful.

Comment: your data columns in  your description are different from  the column names in your query.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to [GROUP BY](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/group-by-modifiers.html) AND you need [aggregation Functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/aggregate-functions.html)

> ```
> CREATE TABLE registrar (
>   `id` INTEGER,
>   `name` VARCHAR(4)
> );
>
> INSERT INTO registrar
>   (`id`, `name`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', 'reg1');
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE registrar_has_division (
>   `id` INTEGER,
>   `registrar_id` INTEGER,
>   `division_id` INTEGER,
>   `is_acting` INTEGER
> );
> ```

> ```
> INSERT INTO registrar_has_division
>   (`id`, `registrar_id`, `division_id`, `is_acting`)
> VALUES
>   ('1', '1', '10', '0'),
>   ('2', '1', '11', '0'),
>   ('3', '1', '12', '1'),
>   ('4', '1', '13', '1');
> ```

> ```
> CREATE TABLE registrar_division (
>   `id` INTEGER,
>   `name_english` VARCHAR(12),
>   `div_type` INTEGER
> );
>
> INSERT INTO registrar_division
>   (`id`, `name_english`, `div_type`)
> VALUES
>   ('10', 'Hulftsdrop', '1'),
>   ('11', 'Modara', '2'),
>   ('12', 'Slave Island', '1'),
>   ('13', 'Fort', '2');
> ```

> ```
> SELECT
>     r.id AS rid,
>     r.name,
>     MAX(IF(
>         divi.div_type = 1 && rd.is_acting = 0,
>         divi.name_english,
>         NULL
>     )) AS marriage_div,
>     MAX(IF(
>         divi.div_type = 2 && rd.is_acting = 0,
>         divi.name_english,
>         NULL
>     )) AS bd_div,
>     MAX(IF(
>         divi.div_type = 1 && rd.is_acting = 1,
>         divi.name_english,
>         NULL
>     )) AS acting_marriage_div,
>     MAX(IF(
>         divi.div_type = 2 && rd.is_acting = 1,
>         divi.name_english,
>         NULL
>     )) AS acting_bd_div
> FROM
>     `registrar` AS `r`
> INNER JOIN `registrar_has_division` AS `rd`
> ON
>     `rd`.`registrar_id` = `r`.`id`
> INNER JOIN `registrar_division` AS `divi`
> ON
>     `rd`.`division_id` = `divi`.`id`
> GROUP BY r.id,r.name
> ```
>
> ```
> rid | name | marriage_div | bd_div | acting_marriage_div | acting_bd_div
> --: | :--- | :----------- | :----- | :------------------ | :------------
>   1 | reg1 | Hulftsdrop   | Modara | Slave Island        | Fort
> ```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=36cfa20ce3868c4beb22c27791f40aa0)*